# Code Connected Volume 2 by Pieter Hintjens?

Tags: zeromq

There is no such thing?
On the last page of Volume 1 P.Hintjens writes about Volume 2 as if it's already published, still I'm unable to find it.
[Code Connected Volume 1, Pieter Hintjens](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf)
What I can find is this: 
[Scalable-C, Pieter Hintjens](https://github.com/booksbyus/scalable-c)

Scalable-C was supposed to be the successor of ccv1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Pieter Hintjens [passed away one year ago](https://twitter.com/hintjens/status/783254242052206592) and probably this book [will remain unfinished](https://github.com/booksbyus/scalable-c/issues/13#issuecomment-213497385).

As you can read [in the preface](https://booksbyus.gitbooks.io/scalable-c/content/preface.html), this book isn't only about zeromq:

> Scalable C is standard portable C plus a mix of other technologies:
>
> - The CLASS RFC defines the Scalable C language style.
> - ZeroMQ provides message passing between threads and processes.
> - CZMQ provides a core C library for Scalable C.
> - Zyre provides local-area clustering for Scalable C projects.
> - zproject provides packaging (builds, bindings, and distributions).
> - zproto provides client-server meta-programming.
> - The C4 RFC defines a collaborative process for scalability.